# Math mode align multiple lines with different number of columns

Tags: math-mode

I have a problem with the align environment. I want to align three lines at the "=" sign and only the first two lines at an additional position.
How can I do this without getting weird spacings? So far, my code produces strange gaps.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    Q(c) &= max_{k} & \prod_{t=1}^T \cdot p(t,c|k) \nonumber \\
         &          & \cdot z(k) \nonumber \\
         &= Q(z(c)) + p(t,c|z(k))
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the alignment as displayed in the code: All lines should be aligned to the = in the first line and the first two rows should additionally be aligned at the product sign.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggested you use an `aligned` for the internal alignment:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  Q(c) &= \max_{k}
         \!\begin{aligned}[t]
           & \prod_{t=1}^T \cdot p(t,c|k) \\
           & \cdot z(k)
         \end{aligned}
             \nonumber\\
       &= Q(z(c)) + p(t,c|z(k))
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

`aligned` is much like `align` but just for internal blocks of an equation.  It takes an optional argument `t` or `b` to specify its vertical placement relative to the surrounding equation.
The `\!` kills a small space that it is automatically inserted in front of `aligned`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Or use `alignat` and `\mathrlap`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    Q(c) &= max_{k}  &\prod_{t=1}^T &\cdot p(t,c|k) \nonumber \\
         &           &&\cdot z(k) \nonumber \\
         &= \mathrlap{Q(z(c)) + p(t,c|z(k))}
\end{alignat}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    Q(c) &= \max_{k }\! \begin{aligned}[t] & \prod_{t=1}^T{} \cdot p(t,c|k) \nonumber \\
         & \cdot z(k)\end{aligned} \nonumber \\
         &= Q(z(c)) + p(t,c|z(k))
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `\phantom`

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    Q(c) &= \max_{k}  \prod_{t=1}^T \cdot p(t,c|k) \nonumber \\
         & \phantom{{}= \max_{k}}          \cdot z(k) \nonumber \\
         &= Q(z(c)) + p(t,c|z(k))
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]